# C++ 2 Byte Array Calculations (char arrays, strings and integers)

Tags: c++, string, char, hex

In C++, I have two arrays:

```
char width[2]
char height[2]
```

My values (hex) are:

```
width[0]= 01
width[1] = 00
height[0] = 00   
height[1]= A8
```

The dimensions are 256x168. I am having a hard time combining the two char values into a string, then converting that string into a "combined" integer for later manipulation.

I've attempted the following **without** success:

```
string sImageWidth = string() + width[0] + width[1];
string sImageHeight = string() + height[0] + height[1];
```

and ...

```
std::stringstream ssImageWidth;
ssImageWidth << width[0] << width[1];
std::string sImageWidth = ssImageWidth.str();
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there another approach? I'm fairly new to C++ and wrapping my head around C++ coming from a C# background. Thanks!

Comment: "_My values (hex) are: 00 01 A8_" but those are not characters and your containers are arrays of _characters_ so your post does not make sense. Also by _combine the two characters_ do you mean just put them beside each other to make a string?

Comment: @tkrn  I do not see where there are arrays of the dimension 256x168 and where there are assigned hex values.

Comment: I should say, it is ANSI encoded and it's representation is as displayed above.

Comment: @FirstStep Those are perfectly valid (hex) values for char types and your comment may mislead asker who said he is beginner in C++. The code is incorrect but that's different issue

Comment: @mvi Does it pop an error if we assign `00` or `A8` to one index of a `char AnyArray[]`?

Comment: As I mentioned, code IS incorrect. This error is also mentioned in Aumnayan's answer below. But you comment is not about code and syntax error. You wrote _""My values (hex) are: 00 01 A8" but those are not characters"_. Taking literally the sentence "my (hex) values are 00..." I don't see any problem in it. I.E. I can say: _"My char values are (hex) 00, AB, DE, etc."_  - and that _will_ make sence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the string as the two chars, this would work:

```
string sImageWidth = string() + width[0] + width[1];
string sImageHeight = string() + height[0] + height[1];
```

since + operator of string can handle a char.
If you want the string to be of the actual numeric value of the char you would need some parsing, like

```
std::string width = std::to_string(static_cast<int>(width[0])) + std::to_string(static_cast<int>(width[1]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Your assignments should be in the format:

```
<char_pos> = 0x<value>;
```

if you're talking about hex values. I'm assuming this is just a typo on the question, otherwise you would be having other problems.

Do you care about the string value? You can skip the conversion to a string completly if you do...

```
int H{(height[0] << 8) | height[1]};
```

As for converting to a string google ["string stream"](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/), which will allow you to perform something like what you're looking for then convert it to a string when you're done.